# Why computation order changes in vectors calculations?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, linear-transformations

### Example

**`Case #1.One person case(Vector)`**

- Let's say that I have taken 2 exams (calculus and economics), whose scores are 60 and 80 respectively.
- I want to calculate **academic achievements** based on the scores of 2 exams. How? I just averaged the two scores.
- The calculation process is equivalent to performing a dot product between two vectors: $${0.5 \choose 0.5} \cdot {60 \choose 80}= {0.5 \choose 0.5}^T*{60 \choose 80} $$

**`Case #2.Three people case(Matrix)`**

- Now there are two friends of mine, Charles and Alice, who have taken the same exams and all of the exams taken by three of us can be shown in a matrix as follows:

$$
    \begin{matrix}
       & Math & Economics \\
    Me & 60 & 80 &  \\
    Charles & 40 & 100 & \\
    Alice & 100 & 60 & \\
    \end{matrix}
$$

- To calculate the **academic achievements** of three of us, the following calculation is needed:
  $$
      \begin{pmatrix}
      60 & 80   \\
      40 & 100 \\
      100 & 60
      \end{pmatrix} * {0.5 \choose 0.5}
  $$

### Question

- When performing a computation (dot product), why is the data (vector, scores of me) located in the right-hand side (**`Case #1`**), while the data (matrix, scores of 3 students) is located in the left-hand side (**`Case #2`**)?
- Even though data is in different forms (vector & matrix), they are same in the sense that they are input. As such, it feels weird that their computation order should be changed based on the form of data.  (i.e. when it is in the form of vector, it is located right-hand side, while left-hand side when the data is in the form of matrix)

### My thoughts

- **`Case #1`** seems natural to me, because **$y=f(x)$** is the norm of the algebra.
- To me, vector or matrix can play the role of `mapping function`. In mathematical equations above,  ${0.5 \choose 0.5}$ is mapping function to project 'scores of students' on the line **$y=x$**.
- **`Case #1`** follows the form of $y=f(x)$, which is **$$y = {0.5 \choose 0.5} * x$$**
- However, the **`Case #2`** changes the order of `mapping function` and `input data`, which is quite bizarre to me.

### Summary

Please explain

1. if ${0.5 \choose 0.5}$ is a linear transformation (`mapping function`) as I thought it would be
2. if the order of `mapping function` and `input data` matters in sense of **$y=f(x)$**
3. why the order should be changed in **`Case #2`**, which is different from **`Case #1`**

Comment: I don't understand your question. You can transpose the matrix-vector product. The order is reversed but the information is preserved.

Comment: In your case 1, your scores are in a column. In your case 2, your scores are in a row instead. If you were consistent, this might seem less odd.

Comment: You could equally well calculate the matrix product
$$\pmatrix{0.5\cr0.5\cr}^T\pmatrix{60&40&100\cr80&100&60\cr}$$ and get the individual performances in a row vector as opposed to a column vector. In other words, you encountered the phenomenon that *taking the transpose reverses the order of multiplication*: $(AB)^T=A^TB^T$.

Comment: @RodrigodeAzevedo If you reverse the order in the `Case #1`, you break the 'column vector' norm. I wrote the scores of my exams a column vector because it is a normal way to write a vector.By doing so, I need to put my score vectors at the back.

Comment: @SteveKass I couldn't keep the consistency because when we have only one observant's information of features, we write it with a column vector. But when we have several people's information, the column vector is tiled to its side and written in rows. I don't know why we have a convention like that but to follow it, I need to reverse the order when moving from `Case #1` to `Case #2`

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I understand your point but when we write a data matrix, it is a custom to put features on column (e.g. calcus score column, economics score column..) and observants on rows (Charls row, Alice row...). As such, I couldn't put the matrix as you did.

Comment: If that is the case, why didn't you do the same in the first calculation also, and write it as follows
$$\pmatrix{60&80\cr}\pmatrix{0.5\cr0.5\cr}?$$

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen When you describe features of one observant, It is a custom to write features as a column. You can check that in the picture in the following url : https://img1.daumcdn.net/thumb/R1280x0/?scode=mtistory2&fname=http%3A%2F%2Fcfile4.uf.tistory.com%2Fimage%2F99FEF04E5B4C38DE1BF61F

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen As you can see in the picture above, to describe a car, you can name many features and those are written in a column vector. For your information the video is from Youtube video 'Mathematics for machine learning' at 1:11. url is as follows :http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a64RYUtIAYc&t=1m11s

Comment: Well, then those "customs" are the answer to your question, aren't they? There is no mathematical reason.

Answer (score 1):

Note that the dot product is symmetric, so perhaps a more intuitive way to write Case 1 for yourself is to reverse the order. Then the data for one person is also given by a row vector, which corresponds to the fact that each row in Case 2 also corresponds to one person.

Comment: A row vector is not a norm and that is why I wrote it as a column vector. One of my questions is that when we have only one person's scores, it is written as a column vector. However, when we have several people's scores, the column vectors of scores are tilted on its side. Can't we keep the column vectors and put the features(scores of exams) on rows, not on columns? Why do we have a custom like putting features on columns?

Comment: I do not see why you wrote the scores for one person as a column. What do you mean by a norm?

Comment: "norm" means the usual way of doing something. When you want to express a series of values in a column, you customarily write them in a column vector. More references such as the image and youtube video are introduced in the comments attatched to the question.

Answer (score 0):

The product of two matrices is a matrix. With the standard definition of the product, the element at row $r$ and column $c$ of the product is the dot product of the row $r$ and column $c$ of the input matrices, in this order.

This is probably easier to remember than if the product had been between rows or between columns. Allowing several execution orders would have been messy.